# python populate.py wont populate my database

Tags: django, python-3.x, faker

After writing the following code and expecting the output to be an updated database with random names, websites, etc., I get no error message and no updated database

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'First_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

import random
from first_app.models import AccessRecord,Webpage,Topic
from faker import Faker

fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search','Social','Marketplace','News','Games']

def add_topic():
    t = Topic.object.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

def populate(N=5):
    for entry in range(N):
        top = add_topic()

        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date =  fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()

        webpg = webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic=top, url=fake_ur, name=fake_name)[0]

        acc_rec = AccessRecord.object.get_or_create(name=webpg,date=fake_date)[0]

if __name__ == ' __main__':
    print("populate")
    populate(20)
    print("populating complete!")
```

please what do I do?

Comment: have you tried converting your script into a management-command? Or try running it with `python manage.py shell < my_script.py`. In both cases you don't need something like `django.setup()` or setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

Comment: Did you trace the code's execution in the debugger ? Did you double-checked you were accessing the same database ? Did you check the second element of your `get_or_create` calls results (the `created` flag) ?

Comment: I'm kinda new to django and I'm following a course buh the course is from a while back and sometimes I run into complications.

Answer (score 0):

i ran the whole code in my terminal and it populated the database